# Proving that $(M_{n \times n}(\mathbb K),\tau_M)$ is a topological space

Tags: general-topology, matrices

I'm trying to conclude whether the following statement is true or not:

> Let $(\mathbb K, \tau)$ be a topological field and let $M_{n \times n}(\mathbb K)$ be the set of all $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb K$.
>
> Let $\tau_M \subseteq \mathcal{P}(M_{n \times n}(\mathbb K))$ with $\emptyset \in \tau_M$.
>
> Let $A \subseteq M_{n \times n}(\mathbb K)$. Then $A \in \tau_M$ if an only if: $$\forall i,j \in \{1,...,n\}, \bigcup_{M \in A} \{M_{ij}\} \in \tau$$
>
> Then $(M_{n \times n}(\mathbb K),\tau_M)$ is a topological space.

I was able to prove the following:

- $\emptyset,M_{n \times n}(\mathbb K) \in \tau_M$
- If $A_i \in \tau_M$ with $i \in I$, then $\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i \in \tau_M$

But I'm having some trouble proving that if $A, B \in \tau_M$ then $A \cap B \in \tau_M$. Yesterday I posted this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4003812/proving-that-bigcup-m-in-a-m-ij-cap-bigcup-m-in-b-m-ij-b) asking help for this specific part. With the approach that I used, I was not able to conclude anything and I was wondering if this statement is indeed true and there's another way of proving this, or if it's false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $M_{2\times 2}(\Bbb R)$, with the usual topology $\tau$ on $\Bbb R$. Let

$$U=\left\{r\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}:r\in\Bbb R\right\}$$

and

$$V=\left\{r\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\-1&1\end{pmatrix}:r\in\Bbb R\right\}\,;$$

then $U,V\in\tau_M$, but

$$U\cap V=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\right\}\,,$$

which is not in $\tau_M$.